# How can I save something without showing a SaveFileDialog()?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I made a program to take a screenshot of the screen. How can I save the image without prompting the user for imput?

Comment: Do you know where you want to save the file?

Comment: Yes, imagine I know where hypothetically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes)` is what you are looking for. Give it a file path and some bytes, and it will write them to that file. Without seeing what image class you are working with, I can't tell you how to extract the bytes from it.

`System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, text)` is also handy for writing text files if you need to do that.

Answer (score 3):

That depends.  If you want to save it to the Temp directory, you can call Path.GetTempFileName() to get a file name where you can save the file.

If there's a particular directory in which you want to save it, you can settle on a file naming convention like screenshot1, screenshot2, etc.  Load the contents of the directory, find the next number in sequence, construct the filename, and save.

Comment: I'm asking about save part, not everything above.

Comment: A reason for the downvote would be appreciated.  It seems like a valid answer to the question, as asked ... before he clarified that he knew where he wanted to save it.

Comment: I downvoted you because I asked how to save and you pretty much answered: "save it". I need to know the how of the 'saving' process.

Comment: I don't agree this should have been downvoted. The prime purpose of the SaveFileDialog is to allow the user to generate a filename for the file in question. Lack of a dialog implies you're getting the destination directory and filename from some other means, and Jim raises interesting points.  This is really a bullshit question, because all you need to do is create a FileStream with the destination filename and appropriate flags. *what* that to use for the filename is the interesting point.

Comment: @Nathan: Read my question again and you'll see I asked how to save a file without prompting for path. The accepted answer does just that; I fail to see how this is a bullshit 'question'.

Comment: Actually, your question says, "without prompting the user for imput." Combined with your mention (in the question title) of not wanting SaveFileDialog displayed, I assumed you meant that you were looking for a way to automatically generate a file name.